# Expected probability that a sub-permutation will reoccur

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value

**Problem**: 6 people are sitting everyday in a random sorted order 1-6, e.g.

Day 1: A-C-B-E-D-F

Day 2: B-A-C-E-F-D.

After how many days is a full permutation, a 5 sub-permutation, a 4 sub-permutation, etc. expected to reoccur?

I understand that the probability for reoccurrence of a full permutation is the birthday problem, but what does the theory look like for the sub-permutations?

With **reoccurrence of sub-permutation of e.g. 4** I mean the probability that the same 4 people will sit in the same order on two different days. Thereby, the exact position in the whole permutation is not imporatant, only the sitting order is important.

Example: **A-B-C-D**-E-F and F-**A-B-C-D**-E

**Note**: This is not a homework question, it is an experiment I am making on my own. The original problem is [Probability that a permutations is going to reoccur](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450119/probability-that-a-permutations-is-going-to-reoccur). Therefore I am not sure that this question even has an answer, as my memories of probability and combinatorics are a little hazy. I would also appreciate it if someone could tell me the topic it belongs to so I can research more about it ony my own.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "the same 4 people will sit in the same order on two different days", do you also require that there's nobody else in between them? I.e. you don't count AXBCYD and YABXCD as a reoccurrence of ABCD?

Comment: Exactly, the same 4 people sit the same way twice, without anyone sitting in between. It doesn't matter who those 4 exact people are, it is sufficient that a 4-people sitting order reoccurs. Sort of like a glued together substring. @Karl

Comment: Are the orders independent across days?

Comment: I am making this as an experiment on 6 real people, who are unaware of the experiment. So yes, the order is purely random and independent every day. @sudeep5221

Comment: Let $p_i$ denote the probability of event happening in a trial. For example, for a sub-permutation of size $4$ is $1/120$.  The expected time to see one such permutation is same as the time to see heads in independent tosses of a coin whose $P(H) = p_i$. It is equal to $1/p_i$. Probability of seeing it on two consecutive days is simply $p_i^2$. If you are interested in the expected time to see two consecutive days of same permutation, try finding number of tosses to se $HH$ with $P(H) = p_i$.

Answer (score 1):

I advise attacking this problem combinatorically.  This way, you can kill two birds with one stone, and determine how many pertinent satisfying combinations that there are, as well as the expected number of days, before such a combination occurs.

Throughout this answer it is assumed that 
$n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}},~~k \in \{2,3,\cdots,(n-1)\}.$

In general, assume that you have $(n)$ people to permute, and are concerned about a specific (**fixed**) sub-permutation of $(k)$ people.

The total number of permutations to run through is $(n!)$.

With a sub-permutation of $(k)$ people, it is as if these $(k)$ people have been **fused into one unit**.  This implies that instead of having $(n)$ *units* to permute, you only have $~[n - (k-1)] = (n+1-k)~$ units to permute.

These units can be permuted in $~[(n+1-k)!]~$ ways.

This means that in general, for each $~(n!)~$ permutations, you should expect $~[(n+1-k)!]~$ *satisfying* permutations.

This implies two things:

- The probability of any given permutation being a satisfying permutation is 
  $\displaystyle \frac{(n+1-k)!}{n!}.$
- In general, you should expect one satisfying permutation for each 
  $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{(n+1-k)!} ~$ permutations.